# How can I extract the value of this json in php?

Tags: php, json, image, long-integer, xbox

I would like to know, how take the value "Tile32px" from this Json:
(http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder) with PHP.

I tried this way:

```
<?php    
$json = file_get_contents('http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder');
$gamer = json_decode($json);
echo $gamer->Gamertag;
echo "<br><br>";  

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$users=$data['LastPlayed'];
foreach ($users as $user)
    {
     echo $user['Title'];
     echo "<br>";
    }
echo "<br>";        
$users2=$data['Pictures'];
foreach ($users2 as $user2)
{
     echo $user2['Tile32px'];
     echo "<br>";
}       
?>
```

This is the result:

SuperDeder

Skyrim
Grand Theft Auto V
FIFA 13
L.A. Noire
WSOP: Full House Pro

h
h
h

Thanks a lot.
Andrea.

Comment: `var_dump($gamer)` PS: why do you `json_decode` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder');


$data = json_decode($json, true);


foreach ($data['LastPlayed'] as $val)
    {
     echo $val['Pictures']['Tile32px'];
     echo "<br>";
    }   

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=superdeder');
    $gamer = json_decode($json, true);
    $users = $gamer['LastPlayed'];
    foreach($users as $user){
    echo $user['Pictures']['Tile32px'];
    echo '<br>';
    }
?>
```